# Can you use files in OrgAssets as the template for a Content Type?

Tags: content-type

I want to create a custom content type and I want to set the template link for the content type to point to a file in the OrgAssets library and then use this across several SharePoint sites.

However, I'm running into obstacles.  It appears that according to [Relative and absolute URLs for content types across site collections is not supported - SharePoint | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/relative-url-across-site-collection-not-supported) you cannot have a content type reference a template file that is in another site collection.  I thought maybe I could make this work with the Content Type Hub, but that site is in a different site collection than OrgAssets.

Is this possible?